# Unopened bags without instructions

Tags: set-database

Can someone help me identify what set these are so I can find the book and my son can build?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This looks like [10667 Construction](https://rebrickable.com/sets/10667-1/construction/#parts):

[image: Set photo]

You can grab the [instructions from Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets/10667-1/Construction).